# Redirect cmd output without log

Tags: batch-file, redirect, cmd

I am trying to write a batch file and I have a command like:

```
encrypt.bat -g firstSeed > C:\MyWorkingDir\key.txt
```

This command creates the file key.txt (it does not exist previously) that contains a string like

```
2014-10-30 11:52:51,430 INFO  [main] security.EncryptionUtil main (EncryptionUtil.java:304) - 45aa826df39cd1b4
```

Now the problem is that I want the file key.txt to contain only the string 45aa826df39cd1b4. I mean, without the log information.
Is there a way for doing so??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the output of the command will not change and the key is the 9th non blank element in the string, the simplest solution will be

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    for /f "tokens=9" %%a in ('encrypt.bat -g firstSeed') do (>"C:\MyWorkingDir\key.txt" echo(%%a)
```

If the format of the line can change, it is better to first read the data and then split it

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('encrypt.bat -g firstSeed') do set "line=%%a"
    for %%a in ("%line: =" "%") do if not "%%~a"=="" set "key=%%~a"
    >"C:\MyWorkingDir\key.txt" echo(%key%
```

In both cases, the `for /f` command executes the `encrypt.bat` command and retrieves the output.

In the first case, we are only interested in the 9th element in the line (delimiters by default are tabs and spaces).

In the second case, the full line is readed and stored in a variable. Then the variable is "quoted" and each space inside it is replaced with a `" "`, so, each element in the initial full string is now a quoted string, with spaces separating each element, and the `for` will iterate over this list storing the value into the `%key%` variable. As the variable is being overwritted, the final value is the required element.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the number of space (or tab) delimited "words" is constant:

```
for /f "tokens=9" %%A in ('encrypt.bat -g firstSeed') echo %%A>"C:\MyWorkingDir\key.txt"
```